# I can not connect on ubutu service port 3050, from my network

Tags: firewall, iptables

I have the Firebird service running on my ubuntu server and it is working fine inside the server. But when I try to use from another machine it does not work. Like a firewall issue.
I did make some tests to check out the ubuntu environment:

```
root@ubuntuserver:~# ps -ef | grep fbserver

firebird  1170     1  0 12:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/fbguard -daemon -forever -pidfile /var/run/firebird/2.5/fbserver.pid
root      3251  3201  0 13:30 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto fbserver

root@ubuntuserver:~# iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:gds-db
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3051

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

root@ubuntuserver:~# nmap -p 3050 localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-12-19 13:34 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00010s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3050/tcp open  gds_db

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds

root@ubuntuserver:~# uname

Linux

root@ubuntuserver:~# uname -a

Linux ubuntuserver 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:04:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@ubuntuserver:~# telnet localhost 3050

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^[
^CConnection closed by foreign host.

root@ubuntuserver:~#
```

I think there is something more blocking the access on it.
I was able to ping this from other machines on my network.

Please, help me on it.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out (place a # in front of) the line:

```
RemoteBindAddress = localhost
```

So that it looks like:

```
#RemoteBindAddress = localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if RemoteBindAddress is hardcoded for localhost in firebird.conf